# WCF Problem with Windows server 2008

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, sql-server-2008

i have a weird problem, i have a wcf hosted in a Console Application now i tried it on 3 pcs all running windows 7 it worked fine, but when i take it to the server (windows server 2008) it doesnt work , now i checked firewall and everythings ,i cant seem to get it to work no matter how hard i tried , im not sure if this is has anything to do with server 2008 or what....
anyone got the same issue ?

here is my Server Config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Gateway.Controllers.ClientController" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ClientService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Gateway.Controllers.IClientController" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ClientService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="Gateway.Controllers.ServerController" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ServerService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Gateway.Controllers.IServerController" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ServerService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="Gateway.Controllers.RoutingController" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/RoutingService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Gateway.Controllers.IRoutingController" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/RoutingService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="Gateway.Controllers.LoggingController" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/LoggingService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Gateway.Controllers.ILoggingController" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/LoggingService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoggingController" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingController" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientController" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerController" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://ServerIP:8000/LoggingService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILoggingController"
            contract="LoggingService.ILoggingController" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoggingController" />
        <endpoint address="http://ServerIP:8000/RoutingService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingController"
            contract="RoutingService.IRoutingController" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingController" />
        <endpoint address="http://ServerIP:8000/ClientService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IClientController"
            contract="ClientService.IClientController" name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientController" />
        <endpoint address="http://ServerIP:8000/ServerService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServerController"
            contract="ServerService.IServerController" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerController" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: i cant consume it , i cant access it , its like server doesnt give me access to it , it times out

Comment: Can you show us your server config and your client config please? What bindings do you use? What security settings? Are those machines are part of the same domain, or no domain at all??

Comment: Do you have the server and client on the same machine? The client config has client endpoints pointing to localhost.

Comment: i changed that to server ip when i deploy it , 

i put it to localhost while im testing only

Comment: The reason it is not working could be a lot of things.  The config you posted will only tell what is not working if we know about the configuration of your environment (eg. part of a domain?Windows authentication?)

Comment: Two recommendations: 1) use the server IP in the service config as the endpoint address (instead of `localhost`), and 2) if you define binding configurations in the client, make sure you use the exact same settings on the server, too!

Comment: i did that , i tried the following for both :

the internal IP, the external IP , localhost , 0.0.0.0 

and i still couldnt consume it 

i made a small console application and listened to the same port using TCPIPListener in the server to test if the port is blocked or something but i could connect to that from client , but WCF never works !

Comment: Can you use svcutil to generate the client proxy while your server is deplyed on the server machine?

Comment: i didnt try that ! i will try it then , thank you , i will post back the result soon

Comment: i tried to generate the client proxy with svcutil and it failed to download metadata from specified server

Comment: Does svcutil give any more specific details? Can you check your Windows event log for any messages that might be WCF-related?

Comment: svcutil just says:

connection attempt failed because the connected part didnt properly respond after a period of time......

i will check eventlog

Comment: nothing in eventlog... this is driving me crazy :S

Comment: now im thinking of something not sure if its related , the country that have the server is a country which have a general proxy so the whole country is behind proxy , but how come i could host a tcplistener and connect to it ? does this means WCF cant work behind proxy but tcplistener can ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!

Start > administrative tools > server manager > features > add feature > .netframwork 3.5 > activate WCF!!!

thanks all